# Which library to use for locally stored JSON files in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I want to make use of JSON in iOS, but my JSON data files are stored inside the app bundle. Which library would be the most simple for this? What can you recommend?

TouchJSON seams to be dead:
http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/ - it redirects to this: https://github.com/schwa/touchcode (404)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/stig/json-framework/:

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a light-weight data interchange format that's easy to read and write for humans and computers alike. This framework implements a strict JSON parser and generator in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at JSONKit: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit. It is pretty up-to-date (last updated June 2011).